# Alinhar label a direita de ícone

Tags: css, ionic

Tenho a seguinte lista de `ion-item` com alguns `ion-label` desalinhados

```
<ion-list id="sidenav">
      <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name="home" item-left></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name="logo-usd" item-left></ion-icon>
        <label>Financeiro</label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name="construct" item-left></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Instalação</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name="log-out" item-left></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Sair</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Como faço para deixar o `ion-label` de cada `ion-icon` alinhado a esquerda da linha vermelha?

Quero que todos fiquem da mesma forma do Financeiro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre por causa do tamanho variado dos ícones.
Um ajuste que vc pode fazer é o seguinte:

No arquivo "app.scss" adicione o seguinte código:

```
.item ion-icon[item-left] {
  width: 24px;
}
```